# "Book something on a date" or "book for a date"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do I use *on* or *for* with a single date?

> - I would like to book annual leave on 08/08/2021
> - I would like to book annual leave for 08/08/2021

Comment: Note the original version of this question used "book an annual leave" which is completely unidiomatic, so I've removed it so as not to distract from the actual question.

Comment: It seems odd that 'annual leave' doesn't (one assumes) mean 'the sum total of annual leave' here. I'd use • 'I would like to book 08/08/2021 as part of my annual leave.' (Good choice of date, x/x/2021, by the way.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Annual leave' as opposed to 'unpaid leave' or 'sick leave' seems an acceptable distinction when specifying how time off work should be categorized, even if it is just part of the annual leave granted an employee, as in " Some people could take three days annual leave and effectively get a nine day holiday". Examples of this usage are quite common.

Comment: @DW256 But labelling all days off work as 'holiday'/'holidays', "I would like to book holiday on 08 / 08 / 2021" is unacceptable.

Comment: Could we focus on the actual question, please? (It's about the preposition.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the UK "Annual leave" in all it's forms is often referred to as "holiday". We don't really use "holiday" in its old sense as much as Americans do. For example we don't think of the Christmas period as "the holidays". In UK English "holidays" are either what Americans call "vacations" (that is taking a trip to a resort, say) or they are annual leave or its equivalent. If someone is discussing the terms and conditions of their job with a friend or relative the friend or relative will often ask "How much holiday do you get?" meaning "how many days annual leave?"

Answer (score 2):

"I would like to book annual leave for 08/08/2021" means "I will be out of the office on 8/8."

"I would like to book annual leave on 08/08/2021" is ambiguous. It could mean, "I will be out of the office on 8/8," but it could also mean "On 8/8, I will schedule my leave for some date after 8/8."

Neither sentence is wrong, but I would recommend avoiding ambiguity in a situation like this. There are some places where ambiguity is good or appropriate (such as for comedy or literary purposes), but you definitely don't want to have any misunderstandings with your boss about when you will take leave.